# iOS: Uploading App to App Store from beta test flight app

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, appstore-approval, review

1) If I have the current Beta Application on TestFlight say version 1.0.2 and 1.0.1, I want to upload 1.0.2 to App Store for reviewing. Will this affect the current testing from using the installed beta 1.0.2 version.

2) Once the 1.0.2 version on live (in appStore), will I be able to use testFlight for beta testing in later version say 1.0.3?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can submit the 1.0.2 version to Apple for review and users will still be able to test it through TestFlight.

2) Once 1.0.2 goes live in the App Store, you can submit later versions, like 1.0.3, to TestFlight, but you'll need to create a new version entry for your app in iTunes Connect. The 1.0.2 record will be locked.

Comment: The answer 2: If I create a new beta version (1.0.3) to testFlight for beta testing, the App Store version (1.0.2) will lock from download?

Comment: Once you release 1.0.2 to the App Store, 1.0.2 is locked down. Users who have the App installed can still use it, but it expires after 30 days so they'll want to install the version from the App Store instead. Also, if you don't release 1.0.2, you won't be able to create a 1.0.3 version unless you delete the 1.0.2 iTunes Connect record.

Comment: Also, when I say it's "locked down," I mean that once you release 1.0.2 to the App Store, testers will not be able to download the TestFlight build of 1.0.2 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, Uploading one version to app store to get approval won't make any impact on another installed version. For example (I'm going to give a new example as your example is a bit vague to me).

Your latest TestFlight build 1.0.2

Previous TestFlight build 1.0.1

and you want to upload 1.0.2 to App Store. In this case Uploading 1.0.2 to App Store won't make any impact on installed 1.0.1 TestFlight version on your device. But if you are trying to send a new TestFlight request it will be sent the latest TestFlight version which is 1.0.2.

2. Yes, You can upload later versions to TestFlight after uploading your current version to the App Store. You can upload 1.0.3 TestFlight version once you upload 1.0.2 version to App Store. Even though 1.0.2 in 'Waiting for review' or 'Ready for Sale' or any other status,  you can upload a new TestFlight build.