# Can I add a new TestFlight version without adding a version to the App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, testflight

I'm not very familiar with `TestFlight`. I would like to add a build with a new version for my app. Do I need to add the new version to the `App Store settings` first?

Comment: Yes you can do it with new version on testflight ,there is no impact on live application
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911445/8687925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every build you upload to iTunes Connect you can decide whether you want to share it with testers on TestFlight and/or submit it for app store review.

When you share builds with TestFlight Apple will review these builds too and you can receive warnings to them too. The initial TestFlight build will be tested more extensively.

> Do I need to add the new version to the App Store settings first?

I don't know about which app store settings you are talking about, but all you have to do before uploading to iTunes connect is set the code signing and provisioning profiles first in XCode and Apple's development portal and make sure you increment the build number on every new upload because the upload will fail if you try to upload a build with a build number already present on iTunes Connect.

Once uploaded iTunes Connect will start processing it and then you can share it for testing with TestFlight or submit for app store release review.

You can read more info about TestFlight in [Apple's dev site](https://testflight.apple.com)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes what I meant is that there is one uploading page in connect for both App Store and TestFlight and then you decide what to do with that build.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Test Flight have nothing to do with Live apps

2 - Versions can contain unlimited number of builds before submitting one to the Live app store

3 - Every time you upload new build it goes under the version number in test flight.

So lets say I am on version 1.0, everyday I'am uploading new build under the same version number

day one : **1.0 (1)**

day two: **1.0 (2)**

And so on, after i upload the final build i can submit that to the live app store, next i will start working on version **1.1** I add that and submit builds to test flight as before, then i submit my **1.1** to the store, and so on .

On app store users will not see anything but the version submitted and current version live is not affected by any test flight version, i can be on version 9 on test flight but 3 on app store, and even schedule an update every month till i reach 9.